# What is Visual Studio 2019 doing in the background on idle?

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I have been constantly bugged by this, sometimes this causes my entire PC to freeze up and lag, I don't really know what its doing in the background. I normally don't close Visual Studio as it takes a good bit of time to compile and load the solution. So I leave it running until I have to work in code. see the screenshots below.

I don't have any window open for Visual Studio other than the main screen and it is connected to our TFS/ Azure DevOps server yet every few minutes I would see the process spike up to 30% and it will cause a lag to everything I am doing e.g. working in a Word document or sending an email.

[image: VS Screen]

Task Manager
[image: TaskManager]

I am not using any extensions other than SQL Server Integration Services, Reporting services and Wix Toolset rest of them I've disabled
[image: Extensions]